# Placing a TextView before EditText element in Android layout XML causes EditText not to show

Tags: java, android, xml, android-widget

As the title says, every time I put a TextView before an EditText element in a LinearLayout, the EditText does not show. When I don't, it does.

I've narrowed the problem down to the TextView's layout_width attribute. If I give it "wrap_content", it works, but doesn't "block" down, and it appears on the same line as the EditText.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
  >

<TextView
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


  <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/marketValLow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35px"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px" /> 


</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're after a vertical orientation to have the TextView above the EditView.  LinearLayout defaults to horizontal.

So add `android:orientation="vertical"` to your LinearLayout definition.

Answer (score 1):

replace this :

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

by

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Exactly. That works, but I need the TextView to (for lack of a better term, I'll use HTML lingo) block so that the EditView drops down below it, regardless of its contents. Meaning, I don't want the TextView on the same line as the EditText.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use relativeLayout and place each child side by side using id's

Example:
<RelativeLayout .... >

<TextView
  android:id="+@id/text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Enter text here:"
 />

 <EditText
  android:id="+@id/edit"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"
 />
```